# Using Maven over bash shell to automate my deploy workflow (github-package-registry)

Tags: java, maven, deployment, github-package-registry

I am correctly deploying my JAR file using the command line below, however I would like to create a `pom.xml` file and invoke `mvn deploy` or something similar to deploy this package to github packages.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

```sh
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.soma -DartifactId=my-module \
  -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=my-module.jar \
  -DrepositoryId=github \
  -Durl=https://maven.pkg.github.com/$USER/my-artifacts
```

In other words, I prefer to use Maven to automate my workflow over bash shell.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The following minimal `pom.xml` should work by executing `mvn deploy` with
the following caveats:

- Replace `$USER` with your actual GitHub user ID
- Put your JAR in `target/my-module-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
- Make sure your `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` has a `<server/>` entry
  with your GitHub user and token

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.soma</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <distributionManagement>
    <downloadUrl>https://maven.pkg.github.com/$USER/${project.groupId}/</downloadUrl>
    <repository>
      <id>github</id>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/$USER/${project.groupId}/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

This should be straightforward if you already have a Maven build for the
project.

(I have run into problems with GitHub throttling requests when trying to
deploy multimodule projects or quickly redeploying an artifact.)